# What/how/where do I get the "link to a valid account" for the purpose of deleting my account?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

My problem is that I want to delete my account. Very simple. How?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's wrong but you know, swearing at people won't help any.

Comment: Why are you on http://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit if you want to delete your Ask Ubuntu account? Try http://askubuntu.com/contact/submit

Comment: No idea. I have no idea at all. I'm trying to delete my askubuntu account...

Comment: "askubuntu.com/contact/submit" = page not found... But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should have been http://askubuntu.com/contact

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Form completed. What a drama - that started yesterday - just to do a simple thing.

Answer (score 4):

I've scheduled your account for deletion. It'll take 24 hours, because they do.

But because I can't help myself, and if it takes, it might actually do your some good in life, I suggest trying to avoid being a complete spanner when you ask for something. You might be behind a keyboard and a screen, but **you're asking a person to do something for you**. Treat them with a little respect and they'll be much more likely to help you.

Anyway. Good luck in your next digital life.

Comment: Thanks for the patronising, arrogant, self-serving lecture. And thanks for deleting my account. Whilst trying to close askubuntu I may have opened another "stack exchange" account or I may not have - I don't know. I'm sorry, I'm unable to understand how this stack exchange system all works - but go ahead and bully me and insult me for not sharing your computer literacy.

Comment: @user104140 you are being neither bullied nor insulted. It is you who came here with the following attitude: *'What the hell is a "link to a valid profile". Just fucking delete my account already!'* Despite this, two volunteers who are not paid for this or otherwise benefit from it, took the time to help you sort your issues out. I hardly think it's "bullying" if, in the process, we also suggest you might want to be civil when asking people for help.

Comment: I find the whole experience is that of bullying, from the kindergarten type awards to the expectation to understand the complexity of the stack exchange system. Computers form part of my life, not all of it and clearly I am not computer literate enough to get along here. Thanks anyway. After some hours of trying to do a simple thing, I lost my temper. Understandable, I think.

Comment: Great. Seeing as your problem is fixed but you're still trying to complain about our deficiencies in trying to help you, I'll lock this now. Best of luck out there.